# More than VARCHAR(MAX) values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables with more than 700 columns/1000 columns.

Now I want to display all columns from this table to `ISNULL(col1,0)` format because when I use `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` and if there are some `NULL` values then they wont be converted to `NULL` and becomes empty strings. So I am trying to replace those `NULL`s with `0`.

In this example I used `sysobjects` table so that you can try it in your ssms.
The result of this is incomplete as neither `VARCHAR(MAX)` nor `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is enough. How do I get all rows rather than few rows here?

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot = STUFF((
                       SELECT ',' +  'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ', 0) AS ' 
                                  + QUOTENAME(name) 
                       FROM  sysobjects t  
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
PRINT @colsUnPivot

 set @query = 'SELECT id,code_name,lkp_value
 FROM  
 (
 SELECT unitid,institution,city,state,zip, '+ @colsUnpivot+'
  FROM sysobjects) AS cp
  UNPIVOT (lkp_value for code_name  IN ('+@colsUnPivot+')
  ) AS up' 
 --PRINT @Query
 --PRINT @Query1
   exec(@query)
```

I mean the code above does not make sense but I can not produce same thing that I have as i have to use sysobjects here.

But above code is throwing an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near '('.

And that's because there is so much data and it's being truncated.

Here is what my PRINT says,

```
    ,ISNULL([opd_
```

So I still think its truncating.

Comment: Is your output truncated by SSMS, or you facing some other problem? Can you provide more detail? I highly doubt that it is as subj states.

Comment: `PRINT` and `SELECT` will truncate the *display* of large results, but you're still able to select the full value.  You just won't be able to see it in SSMS.

Comment: Yep. What they said. varchar(max) goes up to 2GB of data. I can't see what you have there going over that.

Comment: yeah when i print in SSMS its truncated.

Comment: try set @colsUnPivot = '    ' before your statement (thats with a space inbetween ticks

Comment: So as per you guys it will be truncated in print or select. but the original value should be inside @colsUnPivot variable?? and if I process that variable later on it should work?? I dont think thats my case.

Comment: or cast as varchar(max) as well

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the PRINT command will truncate the data for display in SSMS.

I would suggest leaving it as XML and doing a SELECT, if you just need to see the data in SSMS without truncating:

```
   DECLARE @colsUnpivot xml

   SET @colsUnPivot = (SELECT ',' +  'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ', 0) AS ' 
                                  + QUOTENAME(name) 
                       FROM  sysobjects t  
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

   SELECT @colsUnPivot
```

SSMS treats XML output differently and has a higher threshold for truncating the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use SELECT instead of print in your SQL.

```
SELECT @colsUnPivot
```

Also, make sure that these values are maxed out in Results to Grid:
[image: Results to Grid Options]